# Fresh Installation of Magento 2.2.2 is showing Error 503

Tags: php, database, layout, magento2.2, index

I am trying to **install Magento 2.2.2** via a demo directory and getting **Error 503**

While Magento 2.2.1 is installing fine on the same directory.
The Link [**www.domain.com/demo**](http://www.domain.com/demo) is showing **Error 503 on Magento 2.2.2**

While the link **[www.domain.com/demo1](http://www.domain.com/demo1)** is **showing installation screen on Magento 2.2.1**

Please help me, **I want to install Magento 2.2.2.**

Is there any particular **php modules** to be installed for running Magento 2.2.2

Comment: clear your browser cache or try with diffrent browser.

Answer (score 0):

> I have sorted it out :)
>
> There is "mod_version" is missing from server configuration.
>
> New .htaccess file is implemented in Magento 2.2.2 which requires the above mentioned module.
>
> After installing Module, Everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check if maintenance mode is enable or not if yes disable maintenance mode using this command : **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**
>
> or check **.maintenance.flag** in your var folder and delete that file.

Comment: Hi Chander Shekhar there is no .maintenance.flag in new installation. I have added answer to the question. Thanks for the help :)